# How can I enable DNS Suffix support on Android? (resolv.conf search)

Tags: dns

I would like to add Namecoin support to my Android phone (galaxy s) like this: http://dot-bit.org/How_To_Install_Dns_Suffix

I managed to mount the system as read-write and add a resolv.conf to my etc folder like this:

```
search namecoin-suffix
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Now it works fine with nslookup but not with ping or any other program. Is there anything else I have to do?

edit 2012-03-11:

looks like Android does not use resolv.conf at all.

tried these properties but no luck yet (can be read/set with getprop and setprop from the shell):

```
net.dns1
net.dns2
net.dns.search -> space separated domain search suffixes (used e.g. by VPN)
```

There are additional dns server properties that may have to be changed.
The properties are not persistent over a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but a quick look at Android's bionic libc sources seems to indicate that Android might use /etc/ppp/resolv.conf:

(from http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.1.1/bionic/libc/private/resolv_private.h#113)

```
 92 /*
 93  * Resolver configuration file.
 94  * Normally not present, but may contain the address of the
 95  * initial name server(s) to query and the domain search list.
 96  */
 97
 98 #ifndef _PATH_RESCONF
 99 #ifdef ANDROID_CHANGES
100 #define _PATH_RESCONF        "/etc/ppp/resolv.conf"
101 #else
102 #define _PATH_RESCONF        "/etc/resolv.conf"
103 #endif
104 #endif
```

Comment: Good call but still does not work with /etc/ppp/resolv.conf